# how to capture android application package remove?

Tags: android

I have list of apps. I want when  user removed any app then refresh app list. 
Whats best way to do that? I search and found solution using Broadcast Receiver, is it best way? or are there exists direct way to do this? Can I capture  the result of Action Remove intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should add listener for that event like below, If you only interested only in remove just add that only,

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.AppStateReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART" />

            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

then you can add the broadcast receiver like this,

```
public class AppStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public AppStateReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String packageName = intent.getData().getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();

        // Check if the application is install or uninstall and display the message accordingly
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")) {



        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {
            intent.setAction(intent.getAction());

            Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent();

            uninstallIntent.setAction("Uninstall");
            uninstallIntent.putExtra("packageName", packageName);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(uninstallIntent);

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED")) {
            // Application Replaced
//            toastMessage = "PACKAGE_REPLACED: " + intent.getData().toString() + getApplicationName(context, intent.getData().toString(), PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART")) {

        }
    }
}
```

When you get the call back in ur receiver just send one local broadcast and you can listen to your Activity or Fragment or service and handle based on that.

Local broadcast listener in your fragment,

```
BroadcastReceiver UninstallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        updateItems();
    }
};
```

register and unregister the broadcast

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(UninstallReceiver);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(UninstallReceiver, new IntentFilter("Uninstall"));
```

Comment: We don't need permission for this receiver.

Comment: when I must register broadcast? oncreate of activity or ?

Comment: you can register in onCreate and unregister in onDestroy in your activity so that you can get the receiver.

Comment: can you help how to register for installed event?

Comment: you will get as action as **android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED** for both apps installed first time or app update.