# I want to do some functionality when my android app going to uninstall is it possible to detect app uninstall in android?

Tags: android

I want to do some functionality when my android app going to uninstall. Is it possible to detect if the app going to uninstall

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO! Please check whether [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44623121) answers your question

Comment: @Vishnu, it looks as if other apps will receive a broadcast. But not the one that is/gets installed. Did you test this?

Comment: @blackapps Is it? I didn't know, thanks for pointing this out!